# 'Web Audio API is not supported in this browser' error as a part of WebGL build

Tags: onion-services

I'm trying to open a WebGL build with an integrated audio in it, basically a WebGL Unity build.

I am using 9.5 alpha release as the latest stable version doesn't allow wasm anyhow but now even though the WebGL build triggers it throws this error before initialising..

I have tried to enable the permission to use audio for the website as well but didn’t work.. I wonder would there be a way to overcome this last step?

Thanks!

Comment: Fix is; open about:config and enable webaudio.